# How to access outer scope from inner function?

Tags: javascript, closures

How can I access container.a from the inner function c1 ?

```
var container = {
    a : 'blah',
    b : function(){
        console.log(this.a); // prints 'blah'
    },
    c : {        
        // how to access container.a from here?
        c1: function(){
            // and here?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can't `c` use `this`?

Comment: `this` will return the `Window` object inside c

Comment: How about reorganizing it so you can pass in the `container` object into `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* refer to the outer variable that holds a reference to the object, but that's not necessarily stable. If the value of "container" is changed, it won't work. To prevent that, you can encapsulate the object definition in an anonymous function:

```
var container = function() {
  var obj = {
    a : 'blah',
    b : function(){
      console.log(this.a); // prints 'blah'
    },
    c : {        
      c1: function(){
        console.log(obj.a)
      }
    }
  };

  return obj;
}();
```

That *looks* very similar, but by doing this you're guaranteed that the value of "obj" won't change (unless some other function in the object changes it, which would be a weird thing to do).  Now, no matter what happens to the object originally assigned to "container", that `.c.c1()` function will continue to work.

Answer (score 4):

Just refer to container it's a closure

```
var container = {
    a : 'blah',
    b : function(){
        console.log(this.a); // prints 'blah'
    },
    c : {        
        c1: function(){
            console.log(container.a)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, but I should have precised that I was looking for a way to avoid using the name of the container variable! Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

By name:

```
var container = {
  a : 'blah',
  b : function(){
    console.log(this.a); // prints 'blah'
  },
  c : {        
    // how to access container.a from here?
    c1: function(){
      console.log(container.a);
        // and here?
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using the name of the container variable?

Comment: In this case, no. It's not available as `this`, and there's no concept of "parent scope". You need an explicit reference to the object.